# display a set of taxonomy terms according the current user's language. in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to display a set of taxonomy terms according the current user's language.

I have tried following methods:

Attempt N°1:

```
// Get the current browsing lang.
$language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
// Get the view.
$view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView('view_name');
$view->setDisplay($type);
$render = $view->render();
$html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($render);
return new JsonResponse(['html'=>$html]);
```

Attempt N°2:

```
$viewResult = views_get_view_result('view_name');  
foreach ($viewResult as $result){
  $options[$result->taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_tags] = "$result->taxonomy_term_data_field_data_field_tags";
}
```

I'm getting data based on default language i.e english, and if change the language still getting default language.

Comment: When you say "current user's language" you wanna the lang which the user is browsing the website or the preferred language of this user ?

Comment: its the language he selects in drupal system